# Allign text in a div to bootom with bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to align my tittle to the bottom of my container, in my wordpress site which uses bootstrap, how to do this?

I tried playing with positive and relative positioning but I'm getting txt aligned to all the lef or at the very top..

here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid pre-content-banner">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="intro-title bottom-aligned-text">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </div> <!-- end container fluid -->
```

CSS:

```
.pre-content-banner {
    height: 300px;
    background: white url("images/businessppl-bg.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.intro-title {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I'm getting this result:

[image]

Comment: that should be `position:absolute` and for parent `position:relative`

Answer (score 1):

you just convert relative to absolute

```
.pre-content-banner {
    height: 300px;
    background: white url("images/businessppl-bg.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.intro-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container{
    margin-bottom:30px /*this margin == height of h1*/
}
```

or use javascript and change position of element

Answer (score 1):

change to this, maybe the value of bottom should be fit your title. So you can according to your title's height to set it.  Pay attention `width:100%`,because of `absolute` out of the flow.So you must set it!

```
.intro-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the right combination:

```
.pre-content-banner {
    height: 300px;
    background: white url("images/businessppl-bg.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.intro-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

In the .intro-title class the "left" attribute has been pushing the div all the way to the left :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little CSS trick that allows you to align content to the bottom of its container, in a similar fashion to how vertical-align="bottom" works in table-based layouts. http://codepen.io/dfrierson2/pen/myRaNy

```
.container-fluid, .pre-content-banner {
    height: 150px;
    width:900px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;   
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;


}
#intro-title bottom-aligned-text{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin:0;
}



<div class="container-fluid pre-content-banner">
    <div class="container">
         <h1 id="intro-title bottom-aligned-text">Test Title</h1>

    </div>

</div>
```